# Prevent text from wrapping in table until "max-width" is reached

Tags: html, css

I use Java to create an HTML file (regular text file with .html extension) with a table and also fill it at runtime. Each column should be around 300px wide max (for now) but, other than that, the text should use all the space it needs: A column with only short text, like "123", in all cells should be quite narrow, while a column with a 200 character text should span the whole 300px and wrap the text into multiple lines.

The text is passed by a different Java class that I have no control over, so I don't know in advance what text and how much of it is going to be in the table. There could be 3 columns, or 30, and it's fine if the browser's horizontal scrollbar is shown.

I'm currently experiencing problems with short text:

If it contains white space characters (like a space " "), then the column's width is decreased and the text wraps into the next line, once the table is wider than the available screen width and the horizontal scrollbar is shown. If the cell doesn't contain any white spaces, then its width doesn't change.

I know about `white-space: nowrap;` but with that long text bleeds into the next cell, instead of wrapping at 300px.

If I use e.g. `min-width: 100px`, only the text that exceeds 100px is wrapped but then columns with little to no text are also 100px wide, even though they could be using up less space.

**Question:**
How do I prevent short text that contains white space characters from wrapping until it hits the column's `max-width` mark (without overflowing/truncating)? I'm aware I could (probably) check the text's length in Java and change the cell's CSS style to either one that uses `white-space: normal` or another one with `white-space: nowrap`, once it exceeds a certain character count, but I'm interested in a solution that *only uses vanilla HTML and CSS* (is this even possible?).

You can change the width of the right side of the screen in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqprha0w/) to see the problem.

Here's my code:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
  /* min-width: 100px; */
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
    <th>Col3</th>
    <th>Col4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>This is a long text!</td>
    <td>short</td>
    <td>12345678901234567890</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>short</td>
    <td>short</td>
    <td>longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong</td>
    <td>11111111111111111111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>is</td>
    <td>text!</td>
    <td>09876543210987654321</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't get it. Can you explain it by referring to your sample? There's a lot of talk about white space but there's no white space in the sample.

Comment: @wazz `<td>This is a long text!</td>` contains white spaces ("space"). Test it with the jsfiddle I linked, it's easier to see there: Resize the bottom right panel, so the table doesn't completely fit. This resizes "Col2", so "This is a long text!" is displayed in up to 4 lines (column width = width of longest word). Now remove the white spaces -> it doesn't resize "Col2" anymore. I don't want it to resize with blanks but instead simply use a single line, unless the column would have to be wider than 300px to fit the whole text. Only then it should display the rest of the text in the next line.

Comment: I'm talking about white space characters (that's the spelling the editor here on Stackoverflow suggests, wikipedia spells it in the single word "whitespaces") like spaces/blanks (" "), tabs,...

Comment: I thought you must be talking about extra white space, after the text, or something like that. *Spaces*.

Comment: @wazz I edited the question, hopefully it's clear now. Any input, how the whole thing could be done?

Comment: It's clearer, for me. I fooled with it a bit but couldn't come up with anything. I got the feeling that what you're trying to do is two contradictory things that can't happen at the same time. But I'm not really deep into the internals of css so I could be missing something.

Comment: @wazz Contradicting in what way?

Answer (score 1):

You can almost achieve that by wrapping your table inside a container that has a large enough width.

For demonstration purposes, I've wrapped the whole html inside a `<div>` with class `.page`, limited width and scrolling overflow to emulate limited space on a page.

I'm then wrapping the entire table inside a `<div class="container">` that has a width of 1000px. This allows for the table to size its columns according to their `max-width` and contents only.

Trouble is: it makes a very large scroll for a small table that actually barely overflows... This could be solved using javascript though (fix the width of `.container` according to `table` actual width).

```css
.page { /* not required: emulates page flow with limited width */
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: gainsboro;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container {
  width: 1000px;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
  /* min-width: 100px; */
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page"> <!-- not required: emulates page flow with limited width -->
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
        <th>Col4</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>This is a long text!</td>
        <td>short</td>
        <td>12345678901234567890</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>short</td>
        <td>short</td>
        <td>longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong</td>
        <td>11111111111111111111</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>This</td>
        <td>is</td>
        <td>text!</td>
        <td>09876543210987654321</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tested it on JSFiddle (without "page") and the columns keep their size, as expected. Unfortunately I can't use JS with this (HTML/CSS only within the Java class) and I'd probably need way more than 1000px to be able to fit the 30 (or more) columns that are possible - I tested it with 5000px and the scrollable area is really big and would probably be a bit confusing for everyone else too. :/

Comment: @Neph I'm sorry if doesn't help. It's the best I can think of without JS. Maybe you could simply use an estimate of the table's final width, like maybe 70% of all the max widths combined. Otherwise css `grid` should allow to achieve your layout, but it would pose a number of other problems, starting with managing cell borders...

Comment: I won't know the widths until I actually create the table. The dataset I'm currently using for testing contains columns that are almost empty (3-digit number) but also ones that contain 200 words (max width), plus a lot in-between. It's just too much of a guessing game in my case, with the risk of ending up with too little space or a long scroll bar. I'm currently working on the multi-style approach (<40 chars/<300px/nowrap, <=300/300px & >300/500px) and, while it's working, it's not too great either because of the fixed values. I'm actually surprised that nobody's tried to do this before.

Comment: TBH I've tried a few times before and ended up pseudo-solving it with `white-space: nowrap` or solutions like the one I've presented here, or giving up altogether as it was not a big matter for what I was doing....

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to set the widths (in a way that whitespaces don't mess with it) automatically yet - at least without an additional container that I can't know the width of in advance - that's why I'm using Java to assign one of 3 css styles:

```
if(text.length()>40) {
    if(text.length()>300) {
        stringBuilder.append("<td class=\"long2\">");
    } else {
        stringBuilder.append("<td class=\"long1\">");
    }
} else {
    stringBuilder.append("<td class=\"short\">");
}
```

Test HTML/CSS styles (created by hand, jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xmw9szb2/1/)):

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 300px;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
}

table td.short {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table td.long1 {
  min-width: 300px;
}

table td.long2 {
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
    <th>Col3</th>
    <th>Col4</th>
    <th>Col5</th>
    <th>Col6</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td class="short">This is a long text!</td>
    <td class="long1">short</td>
    <td class="long2">This is an even longer text!</td>
    <td>12345678901234567890</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>short</td>
    <td class="short">short</td>
    <td class="long1">longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong</td>
    <td class="long2">long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long</td>
    <td>11111111111111111111</td>
    <td>345</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This</td>
    <td class="short">is</td>
    <td class="long1">text!</td>
    <td class="long2">Something something something!!!</td>
    <td>09876543210987654321</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Short explanation:

- `.short`: <300px wide and uses `no-wrap` because there won't be more than a single line anyway. With the default font and font size it can fit around 45 regular characters without over-flowing (only tested with the Roman alphabet!) but this would have to be changed with other font settings/content, of course.
- `.long1`: Exactly 300px wide. Without this `break-word` would make the column match the width of the longest word if the text contains any whitespaces.
- `.long2`: Exactly 500px wide. If I didn't also set `min-width` the column would only be as wide as the longest word if the text contains any whitespaces. Basically: With whitespaces `min-width` sets the column size, without `max-width` is the important bit.